# one handler on the page or several on elements

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, handler, document

I have a problem, I do not know what to do better:

1. Add a handler for the "document" and get properties with events (for example: `$ (document) .click (function (e) {// e - is object of properties, get the elem = e.toElement})`)
2. add a handler to each element on the page (for example: `$ (el1) .click (..); $ (el2) .click (...);`)

What do you think is better - I think that the first so this method will allow the flexibility to manage events (I have a function that can: connect \ disconnect event, change the function of the event, and add version features)

- Is just one handler instead of a large number

THE EXAMPLE: 
my idea is create the object with a functions which will used when i click on some element of the page, each element have a special attribute 'data-group' and 'data-mete' when  i click on them i get the data from these attributes and use it ti access to the function.

**html**

```
<div data-group="mainMenu" data-meta="home"> Home</div>
<div data-group="mainMenu" data-meta="product"> Product</div>
```

**js**

```
var evtObj = {
   keyboard: {......} ;
   mouse: {
      mainMenu:{
         home: function() {},
         product: function(){},
         .....
      }
   }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a single event handler, but don't attach it to the `document`, put it on the nearest containing element which is available on DOMReady, something like this:

```
$('#container').on('click', '.elements', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $el = $(this); // the element that raised the event
    // do something...
});
```

Comment: why is better = i asking because i want to add... 1000 handlers

Comment: Thats exactly why, 1 handler is better than 1000.

Comment: my idea is create the object with a functions which will used when i click on some element of the page, each element have a special attribute 'data-group' and 'data-mete' when  i click on them i get the data from these attributes and use it ti access to the function. For example:
html
<div data-group="mainMenu" data-meta="home"> Home</div>
<div data-group="mainMenu" data-meta="product"> Product</div>
js
var evtObj = {
keyboard: {......} ;
mouse: {
mainMenu:{
home: function() {},
product: function(){},
.....
}}};

Comment: @MisaGu right, and the approach I have shown you in my answer is the best way to do it.

Comment: But i have a different elements with different classes - but your answer work only with one class in container

Comment: You can select by the `data-group` or `data-meta` attribute if you prefer. So long as the logic is the same for the click event

Comment: i understand that, and i already use the method which you recommend.... and now i what to make a more flexible system

Comment: as i says above I my method give me a possibility to make a version and also disconnect group of elements of events. . . . may be i should make a test .. ^(

Comment: thank you for your help - i'll try to make a test and post results here

Comment: my method works similarly like your (i mean that the count of events is same, at 1000 ms), but if just check the speed of "reading", how faster the PC read the function - my method much better it's faster in 7-8 times (99 933 against 14 873) performances in a 1000 ms

Again, thank you for your help.